# How to add HTTPS/SSL support to a microservice via Azure API management layer without app server having to support SSL?

Tags: azure, ssl, https, azure-api-management, api-gateway

I have a Azure APIM setup that receives the website request and forwards it to the respective microservice node. The website supports only http requests and now I wish to change this to HTTPS/SSL.

The app server on the microservice node does not support SSL, so I have couple of options:

1. On microservice node - change to another app server that supports SSL
2. OR On microservice node - Add a web server (nginx) which does the SSL and forwards the request to the app server (both web server and app server will be on the same node)
3. OR Configure SSL at the Azure API management layer

I prefer to use option 3 so that the microservice node is responsible only to serve requests and the HTTPS/SSL bit is handled by the Azure API management layer. This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview) seems to suggest how this can be achieved for both SSL termination at the gateway and end to end SSL. However, there are 2 problems:

1. This article is about application gateway - and **I am looking for similar solution with API management (API gateway)**.
2. If I wish to use the end to end SSL mode, and not the SSL termination mode (which terminates SSL at gateway), then my app server will need to have SSL feature?

How to add end to end SSL support to a microservice via Azure API management layer without app server having to support SSL?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

API Management (APIM) is acting as a reverse proxy - much like nginx in your example. APIM supports SSL by default and can do SSL termination.

APIM will also talk to your backend service without without any issues - all you need to do is select "http" for the backend instead of "https".

Comment: I assume that the app server must ensure that any url it creates or redirects to must have the https scheme.

Comment: Is API gateway same as API management? I am reading this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview#ssl-termination - is this API gateway feature the same as API management feature?

Comment: API Gateway is the central feature of the API Management product. Application Gateway is a completely different product - although it would also solve your requirement of SSL termination at the gateway. API management can also rewrite URLs returned by your backend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/transform-api#replace-original-urls-in-the-body-of-the-api-response-with-apim-gateway-urls

Comment: Ok so API management provides the same feature as Application Gateway and more. Am I correct to say that - in case of both ssl termination at gateway AND end to end SSL, there is no need to have the app server support SSL?

Comment: The app server does not need to support SSL for your solution to work. "End to end SSL" stops at API Management. Communication between API Management and you app service will not use SSL.

Comment: Here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview#end-to-end-ssl-encryption) it says - In end to end mode..... - application gateway terminates the SSL sessions at the gateway and decrypts user traffic. It then applies the configured rules to select an appropriate backend pool instance to route traffic to. Application gateway then initiates a new SSL connection to the backend server and re-encrypts data using the backend server's public key certificate before transmitting the request to the backend. --So the app server will need support for SSL isn't it?

Comment: You **can** do end to end SSL. But if your backend does not support SSL, it is also possible to only do SSL until the Gateway. This is called SSL termination (same documentation as you just posted).

Comment: OK your previous comment suggested that "End to end SSL" stops at API Management. Communication between API Management and you app service will not use SSL.